# RxJava Operation

Tags: android, rx-java2

I have create customer input class have some fields and i want to filter if the fields meet the validation it should proceed to the repository call else switch to another observer with sealed class type

and I might have defferent fields like phone and others fields must not be empty etc..

I did this

```kotlin
Observable.just(createCustomer)
            .filter { validateName(it.firstName) }
            .switchIfEmpty { Observable.just(NotValidFirstName) }
            // request the create customer
            .flatMap { value -> userRepository.createCustomer(value).toObservable() }
            .filter { it.createCustomer == null }
            // switch filter if not cannot create user
            .switchIfEmpty { Observable.just(CannotCreateUser) }
            .firstOrError()
            // map the result to the User Created result
            .flatMap { Single.just(UserCreated(it.createCustomer)) }
            .cast(CreateUserResult::class.java)
            .onErrorReturn { FailCustomerCreation(it) }
```

```
And I always get empty stream :D

[] (latch = 1, values = 0, errors = 0, completions = 0)
```

Comment: What is your question to be exact?

Comment: I'm not able to get the result of the stream once the filter is correct or wrong with this implementation :D it dose filter but it dose not switch to the ```Observable.just(NotValidFirstName)```

Comment: Do you reach switchIfEmpty block?

Comment: No it dose not i tried many times to break the stream with the validation not working what i want to do i just want to validate all feilds befor requests the repo if any of them not valued return deferent result else return the input and do the request

Comment: Try `.switchIfEmpty ( Observable.just(NotValidFirstName) )`. Note the normal braces around the parameter(s). Same for `.switchIfEmpty ( Observable.just(CannotCreateUser) )`